# How can I replace %20 with - from url using php?

Tags: php, jquery

code:

```
 <?php
    $query = "select * from latest_news limit 0,10";
    $fet = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fet)) 
    {
 ?>
 <p id="news-h3"><?php echo $fetch['news_title']; ?>...<a href="news-details.php?news_tags=<?php echo $fetch['news_tags']; ?>" style="color:red;">[Read More]</a></p>
 <?php
     }
 ?>
```

When I click on link i.e.

```
<a href="news-details.php?news_tags=<?php echo $fetch['news_tags']; ?>" style="color:red;">[Read More]</a>
```

It show

```
best%20engineering%20college%20in%20India
```

Here, I want to replace %20 with (-) from url and get result like

```
best-engineering-college-in-India
```

how can I fix this problem please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.you can use this php built in function.you just want to replace a piece of string by another.

```
$new_url = str_replace('%20', '-', $url);
```

for more information

https://www.php.net/str_replace

2.Use urlencode to encode. The decoding will happen automatically,
and if you want to remove total 20% then use this code.

```
 $url = "one%20%26%20two";
 $a = urldecode($url); // -> "one & two"
```

suppose your page when loading then create your url like this

```
 $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
$base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
```

then use it

```
urldecode($base_url)
```

if you want to use this in url then

```
 echo '<a href="?mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
```

for more information

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: how can I use urlencode while data retrieve from database i.e. <a href="news-details.php?news_tags=<?php echo $fetch['news_tags']; ?>" style="color:red;">[Read More]</a>

Comment: check my update answer.
<a href="news-details.php?news_tags=<?php echo urlencode($fetch['news_tags']); ?>" style="color:red;">[Read More]</a>

Answer (score 0):

You should use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) here:

```
echo str_replace('%20', '-', $input); // best-engineering-college-in-India
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to decode the URL. You can decode it using

```
echo utf8_decode(urldecode($input));
```

Comment: how can I use urldecode while data fetching from database